# Как обратиться к bool-у из другого скрипта?

Tags: unity3d

мне нужно обратиться к переменной bool из другого скрипта, но я не понимаю как это сделать, я хотел сделать подобное просто включением скрипта с другого скрипта, но так сложнее, помогите, ну типо мне нужно другим скриптом включать галочку на обьекте на котором есть этот скрипт
можно ли прописать это через GetComponent?
типо

```
public GameObject player;
player.GetComponent<script> ();
bool = true;
```

так можно?

Answer (score 1):

Для обращения к полю из другого компонент нужно получить сам компонент (скрипт) и обратиться к полю через точку. Также необходимо убедиться что поле публичное.
Пример:

```
var isUseGravity = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity;
```

Comment: я не понимаю сленг, я не понимаю что значит поле это

Comment: поле это бул? или как?

Comment: и как обратиться к полю через точку? Я не понимаю

Comment: @funtot поле это переменная объявляемая в классе, а не в методе

Answer (score 0):

В 1 скрипте сделать публичное поле bool

```
public bool smthBool {get; set;}
```

во 2 скрипте получить ссылку на 1 скрипт:
1 способ - прокинуть через инспектор

```
[SerializeField]
private SmthClassWhithBool;
```

2 способ: в Awake/Start

```
    var smthClass = GetComponent ...
   // все равно будет нужна ссылка на GameObject на котором висит этот скрипт

    //можно применить Find

smthClass.smthBool = false;
```